# how to remove quote for the json export from sqlite in php file

Tags: json, sqlite

I wanted to remove the quote in my result of my sqlite query (for the highchart chart) but I don't know how can I do.
For example this my result :

```
{"name":"minmax","data":["[-0.6,1.6]","[-1,1.4]","[-0.2,7.3]","[2,7.1]","[-0.4,6.8]","[-1.3,7.4]",....
```

And I would like to remove all quote in my query.

This is my php file :

```
<?php

try {    
$db = new SQLite3('../../historique.db');
$reponse = $db->query("SELECT '[' || min || ',' || max || ']' as minmax FROM historique where strftime('%Y', date) >= '2020'");

$rows = array();
$rows['name'] = 'day';
$rows1 = array();
$rows1['name'] = 'minmax';

while ($valeur = $reponse->fetchArray())
{   
    $rows['data'][] = $valeur['day'];   
    $rows1['data'][] = $valeur['minmax'];
}

} catch(Exception $e) {
echo "Failed connexion";
die();
}

$result = array();
array_push($result,$rows);
array_push($result,$rows1);

print json_encode($result);
?>
```

Comment: if I understand correctly, you want to remove the quotes contained in $valeur['minmax'] during the while-loop, correct ? 
Or do you want ALL quotes (including those delimiting the JSON keys) to be eliminated after  json_encode($result) ? 
Is there a specific reason why https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php couldn't solve this issue ?

Comment: Yes, I looking for to remove the quote like that in my result :
{"name":"minmax","data":[[-0.6,1.6],[-1,1.4],[-0.2,7.3],[2,7.1],[-0.4,6.8],[-1.3,7.4],....

Comment: then why don't you just do str_replace('"', "", $valeur['minmax']) , or str_replace('"', "", json_encode($result) ) ?

Comment: Yeah, it's work with the str_replace. I didn't know I could change the result of my query like that.